# Dynamic Stored Procedure in Oracle

Tags: stored-procedures, oracle11g

Gurus, I have stored procedure to has to executed on a dynamic table. Here is how the stored procedure looks like.

```
create or replace PROCEDURE EFX_RECON_UPDATE_SPROC(
    FILENAME IN VARCHAR2 ,
    SOURCE   IN VARCHAR2 )
AS
  TABLE_NAME VARCHAR2(200);
  query_str  VARCHAR2(500);
  cnt        NUMBER(10);
BEGIN
  -- Create dynamic table for each fullfilment system.
    TABLE_NAME := SOURCE||'_BRM_OMC_RECON_T';
    query_str  :='SELECT count(*) from ' || SOURCE || '_BRM_OMC_RECON_T  where PROCESSINGFILENAME='''||FILENAME||''';';
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE query_str;


    query_str:='MERGE INTO '||TABLE_NAME||' T
                USING (    
                SELECT    
                ERRORCODE, PROCESSINGFILENAME,    
                RECORDNUMBER from ERROR_UPLOAD_T 
                ) TMP    
                ON (T.RECORDNUMBER = TMP.RECORDNUMBER and    
                T.PROCESSINGFILENAME= TMP.PROCESSINGFILENAME and    
                T.PROCESSINGFILENAME='''||FILENAME||''')    
                WHEN MATCHED THEN    
                UPDATE SET        
                T.STATUS = ''ERROR'',        
                T.ERRORSOURCE = ''BRM'',        
                T.ERRORCODE = TMP.ERRORCODE';
                EXECUTE IMMEDIATE query_str;
COMMIT;
END EFX_RECON_UPDATE_SPROC;
```

I get this error while executing the stored procedure. The problem is with `FILENAME` and I have enclosed it in ' quot.

> ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
>   ORA-06512: at "PIN149.EFX_RECON_UPDATE_SPROC", line 12

Comment: Print out the SQL statement before you execute it.  It's not immediately obvious to me what the syntax error is but it likely will be once you print out the SQL statement you've built.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the error message the problem is on this line:

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE query_str;
```

It should be:

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE query_str INTO cnt;
```

And the semicolon should be removed from the `SELECT` string.

Although the variable `cnt` is not used elsewhere so I'm not sure what that statement is supposed to accomplish.